# Accessing zsh environment variables from within a VS code dev container?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, zsh, vscode-devcontainer

I'm trying to access an environment variable that is exported in `zsh` on my OSX machine.

`.zshrc`:

```
...
export SOME_API_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
...
```

`devcontainer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "Python 3",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python:3.11",
    "containerEnv": {
        "SOME_API_KEY": "${localEnv:SOME_API_KEY}"
    }
}
```

`main.py`:

```
...

print(os.environ['SOME_API_KEY'])

...
```

Running the script in the container (yes, I rebuilt it) generates an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/workspaces/supreme-rat/main.py", line 21, in <module>

print(os.environ['SOME_API_KEY'])

~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "<frozen os>", line 678, in __getitem__

KeyError: 'SOME_API_KEY'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: VS Code doesn't inherit its environment from any `zsh` session.

Comment: Can a dev container access any environment variables from the host?

Comment: Environment variables are inherited from the parent process. What starts the container, *that's* the process whose environment you want to set.

Comment: Is that vscode?

Comment: I assume so; you mentioned a dev container, which made me think of Docker, but I'm not that familiar with VS Code. macOS is different from Linux, though. The window manager isn't started from a login shell; in fact, there is no login shell except for when you open a new terminal emulator window. Each such window is a separate login shell.

Comment: In this scenario, a dev container is just Docker container.

Comment: You can specify environment variables when creating the container, rather than inheriting them. (For example, `docker container create -e ...`.)

Comment: Environment variables in MacOS (BSD) work the same way as Linux and other Unices.  A GUI application like VS Code is a child process of the desktop environment and won't necessarily see environment variables set in shell dotfiles.  I have the same trouble using VS Code on MacOS without Docker, and for that matter with Emacs on Ubuntu.

Comment: I just had to restart VS code, then it picked up my env vars